# ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature for empty attachment in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have just installed `ActiveStorage` in my Rails 5.2.3 application.
I am using classic CRUD actions to upload an attachment which works fine when an image is selected via my form:

> Processing by Sponsors::MyController#update as JS   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"6hKH0vJIHgd6L2nFBSkpkqSLGXIvnuz95Wmq6I/jbT5NEBngxLY7yNUwF5d+jtN3ZyPFG8rJ/MJ2kXVrWf4SeQ==",
>   "sponsor"=>{"firstname"=>"John", "lastname"=>"Doe",
>   "name"=>"Something",
>   "logo"=>#,
>   @original_filename="Screenshot 2019-05-06 at 10.25.28.png",
>   @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"sponsor[logo]\"; filename=\"Screenshot 2019-05-06 at
>   10.25.28.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame",
>   "X-HTTP-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript,
>   application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01",
>   "id"=>"1348"}

the image param is correctly set. My controller processes the image as described in [ActiveStorage Docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html):

```
@my_object.logo.attach(my_params[:logo])
```

However, when I update a different attribute in the form, e.g. the `firstname` and send an empty logo parameter, I receive an error:

> Processing by Sponsors::MyController#update as JS Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"6hKH0vJIHgd6L2nFBSkpkqSLGXIvnuz95Wmq6I/jbT5NEBngxLY7yNUwF5d+jtN3ZyPFG8rJ/MJ2kXVrWf4SeQ==",
>   "sponsor"=>{"firstname"=>"John", "lastname"=>"Doe",
>   "name"=>"Something", "logo"=>"" ...

=>

```
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature)
```

This is unsatisfying. Even `paperclip` knows how to handle those empty params. I also don't understand exactly why this happens.

A possible solution only is to filter out the param if its empty but that blows up my code:

```
if my_params[:logo].present?
  @my_object.logo.attach(my_params[:logo])
else
  my_params.delete :logo
end
```

works.

Is there any better solution to this? Why would `ActiveStorage` not just skip an empty attachment param out of the box?

Comment: While it doesn't fix the root problem, if you're looking for better readability you can just do in your create action `@my_object.logo.attach(my_params[:logo) if my_params[:logo].present?`

Comment: That will not fix the error as it does not wipe out the parameter. Its stilly trying to update the parameter this way as the empty logo is still part of the Parameter hash,

Comment: Whoops - my bad

Comment: Googled a bit more and it looks like the error is unrelated to Active Storage.. https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageVerifier.html, do you manually call `MessageVerifier` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Nope. I don't even know what that is :D

Comment: This seems to be the only "readable" solution: #1 removing logo param from the param permits #2 call `@my_object.logo.attach(params[:sponsor][:logo]) if params[:sponsor][:logo].present?` - but still I believe there should be a better solution

Comment: I've got the same issue, still no resolution